# Pythonic way to initalize a boolean

Tags: python, initialization, boolean

Is this the best/most Pythonic way to initialize a boolean for this purpose?

```
if start == today:
    b = date_time_obj <= start
else:
    b = date_time_obj < start

if b:
    do_something()
```

I can't think of another way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to run `b` regardless of what the relationship between `start` and `date_time_obj` is so that bit isn't important. In either case of the first if/else, the < operator will always be there so I thought there might be a quicker way to initialize `b`.

Comment: If by "quicker" you mean "shorter", then probably there is. Will it be more readable? Most probably not. If by "quicker" you mean "faster run time", then that should be the least of your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably more common is:

```
b = date_time_obj <= start if start == today else date_time_obj < start
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you really want to have some fun, try

```
b = (date_time_obj < start, date_time_obj <= start)[start == today]
```